# Offline File Transfer XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp, offline, file-transfer, openfire

I need a Openfire plugin component or direction to develop myself to deal with offline file sharing.
In one of our IM applications for iOS (like WhatsApp) we use Stream Initiation to transfer a file using a media proxy. This works ok, however if the recipient is offline you can't setup the bytestream. To overcome this limitation I'm looking for alternatives and one i'm looking into is:

1. If SI fails because recipient is offline the file is transfered to a custom openfire module that store the file and original message
2. A openfire plugin or server component will send the file and message once the recipient becomes available (online)

Anyone have experience with this and or has complemenatry ideas

Answer (score 2):

You can extend and modify XEP-0065 and the Openfire code so that it stores your file for later download.

You can also use something totally different like XEP-0066 for example, upload the files to a web or webdav server and just send the link with OOB for later download.

I am not aware of a standardized XEP for this. So you have to develop your own. The only existing project I am aware of is Jabber Disk
http://dev.jabbim.cz/jdisk